# removing characters in brackets of indefinite length from end of column names in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have some column names in a df as follows:

```
column1 (-)
column2 (unwantedstring)
column3
column4 (4)
```

Note that some columns do not have unwanted brackets on the end and should be kept the same.

I want to get rid of the brackets at the end and anything inside it (along with the space before the opening brackets) to get:

```
column1
column2
column3
column4
```

Am I on the right track with the below?

```
df <- df %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, " \(*\)$"))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In R you need to double escape -once for R and once for regex. You also need to use `.*` not just `*` as a wildcard, so try `" \\(.*\\)$"`, though you could probably simplify to `" \\(.*"`... doesn't really matter if the `(` has a `)` after--you want to remove it anyway, right?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sub` here for a base option:

```r
x <- c("column1 (-)", "column2 (unwantedstring)", "column3", "column4 (4)")
output <- sub("\\s+\\(.*\\)$", "", x)
output

[1] "column1" "column2" "column3" "column4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following solution, however, it's a bit complicated.

```
trimws(regmatches(x, regexpr("\\([^()]\\](SKIP*)(FAIL*)|(?<!\\()[^()]*(?!\\))", x, perl = TRUE)))

[1] "column1" "column2" "column3" "column4"
```

Thanks for the data [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)